# How to choose between gallery and camera in cordova camera

Tags: cordova, camera

I am using cordova-camera plug in to take a picture. However some times user wants to choose between the gallery and the camera. How do I give that option
I have the following code

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
      });

      function onSuccess(imageData) {
        var finalimage = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    });
```

*I am skeptical about changing the destinationType*

Answer (score 2):

By default sourceType is camera. For Gallery `sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY`

Destination type you can add either 
`destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL`
 OR

```
navigator.camera.DestinationType. FILE_URI
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities to declare the options:

```
var options = { quality: 100,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                sourceType: 1,      // 0=Photo Library, 1=Camera, 2=Saved Album
                encodingType: 1,    // 0=JPG 1=PNG
                correctOrientation: true
              };
```

OR

```
var options = { quality: 100,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                correctOrientation: true
              };
```

After declaring the options u can call the getPicuture function like this:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, options);
```